# mybatis IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value

Tags: java, database, spring, ibatis, mybatis

i have many problem with spring e mybatis. This is my spring configuration:
i have the same configuration and ComuneMapper.java and ComuneMapper.xml stay in the same folders. but i have however this error
Somebody to help meeeee

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config /> 

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.aieap" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Configurazione Spring MVC View Resolver -->
    <bean
        id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property
            name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property
            name="prefix"
            value="/jsp/" />
        <property
            name="suffix"
            value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Flow Handler Adapter -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property
            name="flowExecutor"
            ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Flow Handler Mapping -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property
            name="flowRegistry"
            ref="flowRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Flow Executor -->
    <webflow:flow-executor
        id="flowExecutor" />

    <!-- Flow Registry -->
    <webflow:flow-registry
        id="flowRegistry"
        flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <!-- nonaut -->
        <webflow:flow-location
            id="home-nonaut"
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/nonaut/home-nonaut.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            id="logout"
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/nonaut/logout.xml" />

        <!-- aut -->
        <webflow:flow-location
            id="aut/home-aut"
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/home-aut.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            id="aut/nuova-domanda"
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/nuova-domanda.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            id="aut/invia-domanda"
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/invia-domanda.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location
            id="aut/nuovo-operatore-rer"
            path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/nuovo-operatore-rer.xml" />

    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <webflow:flow-builder-services
        id="flowBuilderServices"
        view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" />

    <bean
        id="viewFactoryCreator"
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property
            name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref
                    bean="viewResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property
            name="useSpringBeanBinding"
            value="true" />
    </bean>

    <import resource="jdbc-context.xml" />


</beans>
```

jdbc-context.xm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="/WEB-INF/db.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClass="${jdbc.driver}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
        p:user="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="$jdbc.password}"
        p:acquireIncrement="10"
        p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
        p:maxPoolSize="100"
        p:maxStatements="50"
        p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean
        id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />


    <!-- define the SqlSessionFactory, notice that configLocation is not needed when you use MapperFactoryBean -->
    <bean
        id="sqlSessionFactory"
        class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property
            name="dataSource"
            ref="dataSource" />
        <property
            name="configLocation"
            value="WEB-INF/mybatis/sqlmap-config.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- scan for mappers and will automatically scan the whole classpath for xmls -->
    <bean
        class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.aieap.dao.mapper" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

sqlmap-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <settings>
        <!-- changes from the defaults -->
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="com.aieap.model.Comuni" alias="comuni"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>
```

controller:

```
package com.aieap.web.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.aieap.dao.mapper.ComuniMapper;
import com.aieap.model.Comuni;
import com.aieap.model.OperatoriRer;

@Controller
public class OperatoriRerController {

    @Autowired ComuniMapper comuniDao;


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OperatoriRerController.class);



     @RequestMapping("/aut/nuovo-operatore-rer")
        public ModelMap start() {

        Comuni comuni = comuniDao.selectByPrimaryKey(new Long(1));
        System.out.print(comuni);
        OperatoriRer op = new OperatoriRer();
        op.setNome("ciccio");
        op.setCognome("cappuccio");
        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.addAttribute("OperatoriRer",op);
        return model;
        }


     @RequestMapping("/aut/search-comune")
        public ModelMap searchcomune() {
        List<Comuni> comuniList = new ArrayList <Comuni>() ;        
        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        model.addAttribute("ComunuList",comuniList);
        return model;
        }
}
```

this is the error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatch] in context with path [/aieap] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.aieap.dao.mapper.ComuniMapper.selectByPrimaryKey] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.aieap.dao.mapper.ComuniMapper.selectByPrimaryKey
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:593)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:393)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.setupCommandType(MapperMethod.java:160)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:37)
    at $Proxy9.selectByPrimaryKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.aieap.web.controller.OperatoriRerController.start(OperatoriRerController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

please!!! someone help me I'm hopeless!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I had forgotten.
this is ComuniMapper.java

```
package com.aieap.dao.mapper;

import com.aieap.model.Comuni;
import com.aieap.model.ComuniExample;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

public interface ComuniMapper {

    int countByExample(ComuniExample example);
    int deleteByExample(ComuniExample example);
    int deleteByPrimaryKey(Long idComune);
    int insert(Comuni record);
    int insertSelective(Comuni record);
    List<Comuni> selectByExample(ComuniExample example);
    Comuni selectByPrimaryKey(Long idComune);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table comuni
     *
     * @mbggenerated Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013
     */
    int updateByExampleSelective(@Param("record") Comuni record, @Param("example") ComuniExample example);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table comuni
     *
     * @mbggenerated Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013
     */
    int updateByExample(@Param("record") Comuni record, @Param("example") ComuniExample example);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table comuni
     *
     * @mbggenerated Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013
     */
    int updateByPrimaryKeySelective(Comuni record);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table comuni
     *
     * @mbggenerated Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013
     */
    int updateByPrimaryKey(Comuni record);
}
```

end this ComuniMapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.aieap.dao.mapper.ComuniMapper" >
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.aieap.model.Comuni" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    <id column="ID_COMUNE" property="idComune" jdbcType="BIGINT" />
    <result column="CODICE_ISTAT" property="codiceIstat" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="DESCRIZIONE" property="descrizione" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="CAP" property="cap" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="CODICE_PROVINCIA" property="codiceProvincia" jdbcType="BIGINT" />
    <result column="COMUNE_SIGLA" property="comuneSigla" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="COMUNE_CFIS" property="comuneCfis" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
  </resultMap>
  <sql id="Example_Where_Clause" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    <where >
      <foreach collection="oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or" >
        <if test="criteria.valid" >
          <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" prefixOverrides="and" >
            <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion" >
              <choose >
                <when test="criterion.noValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.singleValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.betweenValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value} and #{criterion.secondValue}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.listValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                  <foreach collection="criterion.value" item="listItem" open="(" close=")" separator="," >
                    #{listItem}
                  </foreach>
                </when>
              </choose>
            </foreach>
          </trim>
        </if>
      </foreach>
    </where>
  </sql>
  <sql id="Update_By_Example_Where_Clause" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    <where >
      <foreach collection="example.oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or" >
        <if test="criteria.valid" >
          <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" prefixOverrides="and" >
            <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion" >
              <choose >
                <when test="criterion.noValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.singleValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.betweenValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value} and #{criterion.secondValue}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.listValue" >
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                  <foreach collection="criterion.value" item="listItem" open="(" close=")" separator="," >
                    #{listItem}
                  </foreach>
                </when>
              </choose>
            </foreach>
          </trim>
        </if>
      </foreach>
    </where>
  </sql>
  <sql id="Base_Column_List" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    ID_COMUNE, CODICE_ISTAT, DESCRIZIONE, CAP, CODICE_PROVINCIA, COMUNE_SIGLA, COMUNE_CFIS
  </sql>
  <select id="selectByExample" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="com.aieap.model.ComuniExample" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    select
    <if test="distinct" >
      distinct
    </if>
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from comuni
    <if test="_parameter != null" >
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
    <if test="orderByClause != null" >
      order by ${orderByClause}
    </if>
  </select>
  <select id="selectByPrimaryKey" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.Long" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    select 
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from comuni
    where ID_COMUNE = #{idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT}
  </select>
  <delete id="deleteByPrimaryKey" parameterType="java.lang.Long" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    delete from comuni
    where ID_COMUNE = #{idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT}
  </delete>
  <delete id="deleteByExample" parameterType="com.aieap.model.ComuniExample" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    delete from comuni
    <if test="_parameter != null" >
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </delete>
  <insert id="insert" parameterType="com.aieap.model.Comuni" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    insert into comuni (ID_COMUNE, CODICE_ISTAT, DESCRIZIONE, 
      CAP, CODICE_PROVINCIA, COMUNE_SIGLA, 
      COMUNE_CFIS)
    values (#{idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT}, #{codiceIstat,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{descrizione,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
      #{cap,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{codiceProvincia,jdbcType=BIGINT}, #{comuneSigla,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
      #{comuneCfis,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
  </insert>
  <insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="com.aieap.model.Comuni" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    insert into comuni
    <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides="," >
      <if test="idComune != null" >
        ID_COMUNE,
      </if>
      <if test="codiceIstat != null" >
        CODICE_ISTAT,
      </if>
      <if test="descrizione != null" >
        DESCRIZIONE,
      </if>
      <if test="cap != null" >
        CAP,
      </if>
      <if test="codiceProvincia != null" >
        CODICE_PROVINCIA,
      </if>
      <if test="comuneSigla != null" >
        COMUNE_SIGLA,
      </if>
      <if test="comuneCfis != null" >
        COMUNE_CFIS,
      </if>
    </trim>
    <trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides="," >
      <if test="idComune != null" >
        #{idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="codiceIstat != null" >
        #{codiceIstat,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="descrizione != null" >
        #{descrizione,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="cap != null" >
        #{cap,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="codiceProvincia != null" >
        #{codiceProvincia,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="comuneSigla != null" >
        #{comuneSigla,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="comuneCfis != null" >
        #{comuneCfis,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
    </trim>
  </insert>
  <select id="countByExample" parameterType="com.aieap.model.ComuniExample" resultType="java.lang.Integer" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    select count(*) from comuni
    <if test="_parameter != null" >
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </select>
  <update id="updateByExampleSelective" parameterType="map" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    update comuni
    <set >
      <if test="record.idComune != null" >
        ID_COMUNE = #{record.idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="record.codiceIstat != null" >
        CODICE_ISTAT = #{record.codiceIstat,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.descrizione != null" >
        DESCRIZIONE = #{record.descrizione,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.cap != null" >
        CAP = #{record.cap,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.codiceProvincia != null" >
        CODICE_PROVINCIA = #{record.codiceProvincia,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="record.comuneSigla != null" >
        COMUNE_SIGLA = #{record.comuneSigla,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.comuneCfis != null" >
        COMUNE_CFIS = #{record.comuneCfis,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
    </set>
    <if test="_parameter != null" >
      <include refid="Update_By_Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </update>
  <update id="updateByExample" parameterType="map" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    update comuni
    set ID_COMUNE = #{record.idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      CODICE_ISTAT = #{record.codiceIstat,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      DESCRIZIONE = #{record.descrizione,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      CAP = #{record.cap,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      CODICE_PROVINCIA = #{record.codiceProvincia,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      COMUNE_SIGLA = #{record.comuneSigla,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      COMUNE_CFIS = #{record.comuneCfis,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    <if test="_parameter != null" >
      <include refid="Update_By_Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </update>
  <update id="updateByPrimaryKeySelective" parameterType="com.aieap.model.Comuni" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    update comuni
    <set >
      <if test="codiceIstat != null" >
        CODICE_ISTAT = #{codiceIstat,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="descrizione != null" >
        DESCRIZIONE = #{descrizione,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="cap != null" >
        CAP = #{cap,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="codiceProvincia != null" >
        CODICE_PROVINCIA = #{codiceProvincia,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      </if>
      <if test="comuneSigla != null" >
        COMUNE_SIGLA = #{comuneSigla,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="comuneCfis != null" >
        COMUNE_CFIS = #{comuneCfis,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
    </set>
    where ID_COMUNE = #{idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT}
  </update>
  <update id="updateByPrimaryKey" parameterType="com.aieap.model.Comuni" >
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Tue Jan 08 16:52:16 CET 2013.
    -->
    update comuni
    set CODICE_ISTAT = #{codiceIstat,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      DESCRIZIONE = #{descrizione,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      CAP = #{cap,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      CODICE_PROVINCIA = #{codiceProvincia,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      COMUNE_SIGLA = #{comuneSigla,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      COMUNE_CFIS = #{comuneCfis,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    where ID_COMUNE = #{idComune,jdbcType=BIGINT}
  </update>
</mapper>
```

Answer (score 15):

Hi this problem usually is connected to mapper locations.
So try to set the mapperLocation property in your [SqlSessionFactory](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/factorybean.html) bean:

```
<property name="mapperLocations" 
value="classpath*:pathWhereYouHaveMapper/*Mapper.xml" />
```

Hope it help!

Comment: In my case, config was set to application.yml as `mybatis:` `mapper-locations: classpath*:sql/oracle/*.xml` and real location was without sql folder. So I created sql folder and moved oracle folder into it.

Answer (score 13):

**There can be several reasons...!**

- -> SQL Syntax (maybe a single small query has an extra "," at the end of the select)
- -> Classpath issues ,cannot resolve jar dependencies
- -> Also this can coming due an file encoding issue or illegal xml characters embed in your '*Mapper.xml' file. (so watch out for your editor..!)

**most importantly you should use same names for.**

- interface = xxx.yyy.mappers.SettingMapper.class
- mapper file = /xxx/yyy/mappers/SettingMapper.xml
- mapper namespace = xxx.yyy.mappers.SettingMapper

Comment: In my case, i was selecting a string and putting it in to date object. mismatched result types. changed to selecting a string in to a string field and error resolved.

Comment: Yeah it happens. We expect it to fall back to ToString() but it won't trigger.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.ct...`  I have hitted this issue before.  It means that mapped statements collection that is from the `*ModelMapper.xml` file does not contain the method defined in your `*ModelMapper.java` file. 

In my case, sometimes it is caused by the mismatch between the naming of t he xml file& the java file.

Comment: I ran into this issue and upvoted this answer in 2020 already. Now, in another legacy project, I ran into the opposite error stating that "mapped statements collections already contains ..." For the love of everlasting ****, I cannot stress enough the fact that when you're allowing Spring to autoconfigure USE THE SAME NAMES.

Answer (score 11):

This usually means mybatis can't find the mapping you refer to. Perhaps you forgot to add the *Mapper.xml file to **mybatis-config.xml** (which is a standard config file for MyBatis)

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="org/mybatis/builder/AuthorMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

See more in documentation http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers

Answer (score 3):

In My case what happened is there were was a **TYPO in my method name** in the mapping xml file.
 When I have changed the DAO name, I forgot to change in the xml, it may help someone else.

Comment: Also `parameterType` and `resultType` must match exactly after the refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the other answers, you also have to

> **Check for duplicate method names**

This error comes in the log at last.

```
IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value
```

Ignore the above message and simply move up your logs and look for the first error message in the logs. The first error I got was,

```
ERROR [main] mapper.MapperFactoryBean (MapperFactoryBean.java:83) - Error while adding the mapper 'interface com.xyz.mappers.UserMapper' to configuration.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection already contains value for com.xyz.mappers.UserMapper.getAllUserDetails
```

The error clearly points out that, the method `getAllUserDetails` already exists in the `UserMapper` interface(with different number of parameters). Duplicating the method names also throws this error. (The penalty for copy-pasting codes) :P

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated `id` in mapper.xml also throws such exception.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. In addition to the possibility of the above answer I try to use this way which solve the problem:

The method name should be same in `dao` and `mapper.xml`, in my case method name not is same. So you must be sure that they are the same.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you may register your mapper in `mybatis-config.xml` file

```
<configuration>
    <properties resource="db.dev.properties">
     ...
    </properties>

    <typeHandlers>
        <package name="com.project.model.typehandlers"/>
    </typeHandlers>

    <environments default="development">
     ...
    </environments>

    <mappers>
      <mapper resource="com/project/model/xml/SomeMapper.xml"/>
      // other mapper here
    </mappers>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: I use the Java object setting:     configuration.addMappers("com.some.package.mapper");
Hopefully this scans all the mappers in the package, but I'm no longer sure because it only worked when I had one mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mybatis the same way as you. Your code looks fine. Even I'm not sure if there is a problem with type mappings. Try two following tips to fix your problem:

1. change java type to mybtis aliases
   a) "java.lang.Long" -> "long", b) "com.aieap.model.Comuni" -> "comuni"
2. try to add alias instead of XML mapping
   @org.apache.ibatis.type.Alias("comuni") to com.aieap.model.Comuni, remove xml typeAlias, add spring configuration to your org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean:

Good luck,
Martin

Comment: thanks for your response but don't work. Maybe there may be some problem in libraries:

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Then I found that all requests who has the query mappings defined on that mapper.xml having same error.

May be this is because of improper build of WAR or improper deployment to server.
Anyway, I deleted that WAR file and re-deployed again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exception too. In my case the mapper xml file was present in a JAR included in the classpath, but somehow it could not be found by the MapperScannerConfigurer. I came to know of this by reading the logs. You should read the logs and check the line of the following format to know whether there are any mappers being found. I had to give the root path to it, after which it found my mapper.

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:423 - Resolved location pattern [classpath*:*.xml] to resources [URL [jar:file:/home/user/src/tomcat8/webapps/example/WEB-INF/lib/ExampleDao-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/TestMapper.xml]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have mapped `mybatis.config` in the properties file.

add this line in application.properties file.

```
mybatis.config=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I read an artical saying another possibility - maven build resources issue

https://www.cnblogs.com/javaxubo/p/16608104.html